# which one is more natural? government "forced" or "ordered" to reconstruct the apartment?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request

> "government **forced to** reconstruct the old apartment."
>
> "government **ordered to** reconstruct the old apartment."

which one is more natural between somebody "forced to reconstruct ..." or "order to reconstruct ..."?
Or is it more natural if I make "the apartment" a subject? as in

> "the old apartment is forced to be reconstructed."
>
> "the old apartment was chosen as ..."

Or is there any other verb that fits here?

Comment: You are missing `was` or `someone`: _The government was forced to reconstruct the old apartment due to health reasons_ or _The government  forced the landlord to reconstruct the old apartment due to health reasons_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are equally natural but mean different things.

*Force* implies some kind of *coercion*:

> Their mother **forced** the the boys to clean up their rooms (threatening to take away their cell phones if they didn't).

*Order* implies some kind of *authoritative* statement.

> The court **ordered** the boys to clean up the damage to their neighbor's yard from their "prank".

If the government didn't want to reconstruct the apartment, they might have had to be *forced* to do it.  If some higher authority required it of them, then you can say the government was *ordered* to do it.

Synonyms for "ordered":  *commanded, directed, instructed, mandated, requested, told, warned, charged*, and others.

Synonyms for "forced": *compelled, demanded, obliged, pressured, required, coerced, strong-armed*, and others.

Some of these, like *commanded* or *mandated*, include both definitions.

Comment: Oh i think I chose the wrong word. I didn't know how to use "force" properly. What I wanted to write was "the apartment was forced to be reconstructed (by the government.", not "the government was ordered or forced to do that." Then should I write like "if my apartment is forced to be reconstructed, i'll be kicked out..." ?

Comment: @dbwlsld  Either way.  "Force" implies *coercion* so it's appropriate if 1) you don't want to do it, and 2) there is some kind of penalty or threat if you don't.